# Product Listing Page: Set Grid mode for Mobile (Below 720) & List mode in Desktop Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, category

I want to configure Product Listing Page such that Grid mode should be active for Mobile (Below 720) & List mode for Desktop. already implemented via javascript but having issues in performance at google pageinsight So want to try a different approach.

I'm trying to use the below code to get the header on the category list page.
& trying to set depending on the device. But till now it is not working. Let me know if their is ay alternate option is available.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader
$userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();
$isMobile = \Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match($userAgent, $_SERVER);